# How to rename a local APT repository?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, apt, dpkg, repository

I follow the steps in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/176546) to create a custom repository, but I want to rename it. I can't find any way to do it. Can you please help me?

Comment: What do you mean by rename?  Repositories don't have names.  Do you mean the suite name (e.g `bionic`/`focal`)?  The component (e.g. `main`, `universe`)?  The path (e.g. `/usr/local/mydebs`)?

Comment: Let me elaborate on this. I downloaded a package and used the dpkg-scanpackages program, now after changing the sources file I can install the package via apt-get. But the name of this package is beyond my control. I want to name this package say MyRepository, to be able to install it by writing apt-get MyRepository, instead of apt-get AnotherDudesName.

Comment: @DiplomateProgrammer What do you mean by repository here? Are you talking about package name?

Comment: I don't know the terminology. I created a local repository using the dpkg-scanpackages command like in the post I linked. Everything is fine, but there seems to be no way to change the name of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to know how to rename a package.  There are two ways to do this.   In this example, I'm going to change the name of `cowsay` to `mysay`

### From source

Download the debian  (or ubuntu) source package, rename the files as appropriate, replace the old name with the new name in the `debian/*` directory (that's what the `sed` lines are doing, then build it with `dpkg-buildpackage`.

Be a little careful, because some packages may have build rules which depend on the package name and may not be as trivial as cowsay.  This is probably the toughest option.

```
apt source cowsay
mv cowsay-3.03+dfsg2 mysay-3.03+dfsg2
mv cowsay_3.03+dfsg2-8.dsc mysay_3.03+dfsg2-8.dsc
mv cowsay_3.03+dfsg2.orig.tar.gz mysay_3.03+dfsg2.orig.tar.gz
cd mysay-3.03+dfsg2/
sed -i 's/\bcowsay\b/mysay/g' debian/changelog debian/control
sed -i 's./debian/cowsay./debian/mysay.g' debian/rules
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us
```

### From binary

Get the *.deb you want to manually split the archive up, edit the `control` file and then put it back togeather.

```
apt download cowsay
mkdir mysay && cd mysay

# Split everything up
ar -x ../cowsay_3.03+dfsg2-8_all.deb
mkdir control
tar -xf control.tar.xz -C control

# CHange the package name
sed -i 's/cowsay/mysay/' control/control

# Put the control file back togeather
cd control
tar -cf control.tar.xz *
mv control.tar.xz ../
cd ..
rm -r control

# Put the rest back togeather
ar r ../mysay_3.03+dfsg2-8_all.deb debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.xz
```

### From binary (method 2)

This one simplifies the re-combining process. This is probably the easiest method.

```
apt download cowsay
ar x cowsay_3.03+dfsg2-8_all.deb 
mkdir -p mysay/DEBIAN
tar -xf control.tar.xz -C mysay/DEBIAN
tar -xf data.tar.xz -C mysay/
sed -i 's/cowsay/mysay/' mysay/DEBIAN/control
dpkg-deb -b mysay
```

---

A few final notes:

- If you try to install `cowsay` and `mysay` on the same machine, one of the packages will fail.  That's because they both supply the same files, so it's impossible for your system to know which owns it.  A way to make this foolproof is to add a `Conflicts: cowsay` to the control file of `mysay`.
- Renaming packages is a little strange.  It is sure to cause the conflicts mentioned above.  I not sure I can picture a case where this is necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I think this addresses my issue.

Comment: However, I tried a similar approach with binary before and it didn't work. I changed the control file in the control.tar.xz directory of the archive, changing Package from the original name to my own. But when I call the dpkg-scanpackages command, the control file is once again changed to what it was before and it doesn't work.
Update: it seems for some reason there's an archive inside the archive, so that's why it wasn't updated. Probably should work if processed carefully.